# Why does `blockingGet()` works, but `assertValue()` doesn't when writing to, then reading from, a DB in RxJava?

Tags: java, rx-java

I am running a test where I run a write, then read operations:

```java
emailRepository.insertEmail(email); // Returns a Completable
emailRepository.getEmail(email); // returns a Maybe<String>
```

If I try to test it using `TestObserver<String>` as below, I get an empty `Maybe` from `getEmail()` and the test fails:

```
emailRepository.insertEmail(email)
  .andThen(Maybe.defer(() -> emailRepository.getEmail(email)))
  .test()
  .assertValue(email);   // fails -- empty Maybe
```

However, if I run it with `blockingGet()`, the same test works:

```
String emailFromDb = emailRepository.insertEmail(email)
  .andThen(Maybe.defer(() -> emailRepository.getEmail(email)))
  .blockingGet();

assertValue(email,emailFromDb);    // succeeds
```

I thought by chaining the `test()` method I would be decreasing the risk of race conditions, but weirdly this does not seem to be the case.

Could it be just a coincidence that `blockingGet()` is working?
My understanding was that once the task is handed over to the database (MySql, in this case), the `Completable` would complete but the DB may not have finished the write. But if that were the case, then shouldn't I be seeing it fail some times as well with `blockingGet()`? Or am I misinterpreting things here?

Comment: If `insertEmail` runs on some other thread, you'll have to wait for it to finish. `blockingGet` does this. For `test()`, you'll have to use `awaitDone()` before asserting anything.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.